# SSMS - DB context menu does not include Database Upgrade option

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/upgrade-dbcompat-using-qta?view=sql-server-2017 and https://www.sqlshack.com/database-upgrade-using-the-query-tuning-assistant-wizard-in-ssms-18/ DB context menu has to include option **Database Upgrade** under **Tasks**.
Hovever in my case the option Database upgrade is missing.
[image: see image]

I'm using SSMS 18.10 (upgraded from 18.7.1).
Tried on different databases on different versions of SQL Server (including 2019), no DB has such option in Tasks.
Why is the context menu incomplete?

**UPDATE:**

1. installed SQL Server 2012 Express
2. created DB and restored from BAK created on 2008 R2, Database Upgrade option still not present in Tasks
3. upgraded SQL Server to 2019 Express, Database Upgrade option still not present in Tasks

**UPDATE #2:**

1. created a DB on SQL Server 2019 **Standard** (running on Windows Server)
2. set lower compatibility level
3. heureka, QTA available

Comment: This implies your database isn't in an older compatibility mode. I just checked a database we have in mode 110 on a 2019 instance, and the option is there.

Comment: I just created DB on 2008 R2, backed it up, than created DB on 2019 and restored it from the backup from 2008 R2. Compatibility level is 100, but the option still not present. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are missing the permissions for the task. Check if you are DB_OWNER.

Comment: Checked, I'm the DB_OWNER. Tried with Widndows Auth and SQL Auth, no success.

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed SQL 2019 EXPRESS on my pc.....
SSMS does not display Database Upgrade option.

SSMS does display Database Upgrade option when using SQL 2019 DEVELOPER on my PC

Maybe that is your issue?

this is the full list of options in SQL Developer[image]

Comment: Yes, it's about the **Edition** of SQL Server. Just installed 2017 Developer and it's there. Even Standard edition includes Database Upgrade, the Express edition does not. Shame no of the articles I've read does not mention this fact.

Comment: great...so care to mark this as the answer ?

Comment: Actually, now that i think about it, the documentation *does* tell you this, @pburgr . [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2019 (15.x) -  Management tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMS): *"Database Tuning Advisor (DTA): **Express with Advanced Services** - No | **Express** - No"*